# Split a string into blocks of three?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a String of digits. I need to group those digits in block of length three and separate by single dash. If necessary, the final block or the last two blocks can be of length two.

```
    String abc = "12-10 23 5555 8361";
    String hello = abc.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
```

Now, how can I group them in blocks of length three?

Expected result is

```
121-023-555-583-61
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the string should become?

Comment: What's expected output ? What about `12-10` ?

Comment: Check out my solution in C++ without regular expressions and works for every possible case. I am inserting space instead of '-' https://codeshare.io/5ZRWJ7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `\G` within a lookbehind based regex:

```
String abc = "12-10 23 5555 8361";
String hello = abc.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
System.out.println(hello.replaceAll("(?<=\\G\\d{3})", "-"));
// => 121-023-555-583-61
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/36efro)

The `(?<=\\G\\d{3})` regex contains just a zero-width assertion that matches a position at the start of the string or at the end of the last successful match (`\G`) that is followed with 3 digits (`\d{3}`). In Java regex, this pattern works fine in the current scenario (i.e. `\G` moves the regex index from within lookbehind). This won't work in Android though.

**UPDATE**:

For the updated requirements, you can use a several step approach like

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
     String s = "0 - 22 1985--324"; // => 022-198-53-24
     run(s);
     s = "555372654";  // => 555-372-654
     run(s);
     s = "12-10 23 5555 8361"; // => 121-023-555-583-61
     run(s);
}
public static void run(String abc) {
    String hello = abc.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
    hello = hello.replaceAll("(?<=\\G\\d{3})(?!$)", "-");
    System.out.println(hello.replaceAll("\\b(\\d{2})(\\d+)-(\\d)$", "$1-$2$3"));
}
```

See [another IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/am1Sp7)

The regex is updated with `(?!$)` at the end that fails the match at the end of the string.

The `.replaceAll("\\b(\\d{2})(\\d+)-(\\d)$", "$1-$2$3")` is necessary to re-arrange the 2 last digit groups at the end: if there are 3 or more digits followed with a hyphen and then just 1 digit, we need to move the hyphen after the first 2 digits, and move the other digits right after this hyphen.

Comment: Thanks, @Wiktor Stribiżew , this method works in most cases but for example with this string "ABC372654" did not work, it could not separate the string into blocks of 3, do you have any idea?

Comment: @mi_mo There is no word boundary between `C` and `3`. There is no hyphen in this string either. Use a numeric boundary, `.replaceFirst("(?<!\\d)(\\d{2})(\\d+)(\\d)$", "$1-$2$3")`. Or`.replaceFirst("(?<!\\d)(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$", "$1 $2 $3")`, I do not know your requirements. You might want to remove the numeric boundary, too.

Comment: i have some strings like these: "ABC372654", "0 - 22 1985--324", I want to remove all none-numeric and alphabetic characters and split them into blocks of three and for last block or for 2 last blocks the blocks can have 2 characters(if last block has less than 3 characters for example remained just 4 characters) for example this string "0 - 22 1985--324" should be like this "022 198 53 24" but this string "ABC372654" should be "ABC 372 654"

Comment: @mi_mo 1) Remove non-alnum chars with `abc.replaceAll("\\P{Alnum}+", "")`, 2) then use `.replaceAll("(?:\\G|(?<!\\d))(?:\\d{3}(?=(?:\\d{3})+\\d{0,2}$)|\\d{3}$|\\d{2}(?!$))","$0 ").trim()`

Comment: Tnx, could you please guide me about the Regex that you used for example: `(?:\\G|(?<!\\d))(?:\\d{3}(?=(?:\\d{3})+\\d{0,2}$)|\\d{3}$|\\d{2}(?!$))","$0 ")`, how can I figure out them? i could not understand their meaning by using online Regex compilers like Regexr.com

Answer (score 1):

You could also group three digits and replace with captured group and `-`.

**Regex:** `(\d{3})`

**Replacement to do:** Replace with `\1-`

**Java Code**

```
String abc = "12-10 23 5555 8361";
String hello = abc.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
System.out.println(hello.replaceAll("(\\d{3})", "$1-"));
```

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tF2aS0/1)**

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/juSraC)**

Comment: For this number `555372654` it ends with trailing `-`.

Comment: @user1950349: Let me check.

Comment: And each block should have atleast two digits so for this example `0 - 22 1985--324` it fails as I get `022-198-532-4`. Instead I should tget `022-198-53-24`